# Trying to display from arraylist on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

im new to java swing, and Ive got a little problem. 
So I've got a class `Flight.java`. In there I have a method `displaySeat2D()`.
First I had this done with the scanner. Now Im using swing. So basically I made text fields to take in a number of seats and a number of rows. Now Im trying to display this in `JPanel`. Guess Id have to use `JLabel` and display it there. Not realy sure. So instead of `0` and `1`, id like to have seats and rows displayed like squares for example. Or if its possible id try to keep it simple and display it like in Eclipse console with `0`.

This is the code.

// FLIGHT class:

```
public void displaySeat2D(){
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySeatPassenger.length; i++) {//line
        System.out.println("");
        for (int j = 0; j < arraySeatPassenger[i].length; j++) {// seat
            if (arraySeatPassenger[i][j] == null) {
                System.out.print("0");//
            } else {
                System.out.print("1");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");     
}
```

// UI (display part):

```
lblDisplay.setForeground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
btnDisplayv.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
});
```

// Piece of UI

http://i44.tinypic.com/ajnlo3.jpg

That's basically it. I could use help when I click this button some field would appear with for example 4(seats)x4(rows). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using a `JTable`. Each seat can be represented by individual cells with the table managing the alignment of the characters in the `ArrayList`. For more see [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: That's a no go, bcoz the user can set for example seats on airplane 5x5, 1x1.. its random... When I used scanner and some entered like 4x4. It would display it like this: 0000 and 0000 in next line and so on

Comment: Your grid can be configurable also. The more cells there are, the less each will occupy obviously

Comment: Is there an easier way with that paint method? For example instead of System.out.print("0");  Smth like g.setColor.Green or smth like that.. In that case how do I use that paint method...

Comment: Using custom painting would be more difficult especially if you're new to Swing. (In that case you would be using `paintComponent`).

Comment: Is there a way to display it simple like in eclipse console with just numbers "0" for each seat created. So I dont have to use nothing graphical and basicly keep it simple as possible?

Comment: You could use a `JTable`. See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Hmm.. well if i just write down flight.displaySeat2D() it display it in eclipse console thats normal. How to make it display it in label? Obviously labelldisplay.setTest(flight.displaySeat2D()); is not working :))

Comment: No forget using a `Jlabel`. It will be a nightmare to align the characters, `JTable` does the alignment for you

Comment: was reading to fast didnt see u wrote JTable in a line above this:) Ill give it a try.